# How to get the position of a targeted element after ajax call in a slider content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to get the position of the targeted element after ajax call in a slider content, but I am having trouble getting the code to work here. Here is my ajax (load) code:

```
// Load the article into container_article.
container_article.load(path, function(){

    // Get the width of the loaded article first.
    var width_article = container_article.width();

    // Add the article width into the existing content container width.
    scroll_content.width(scroll_content.width() + width_article + 2);

    // Get the position of current requested article.
    var block_request = $('.block-'+ request).css({background:'red'});
    var position_request = $('.block-'+ request).position();
    alert(position_request.left);
    //alert(block_request.offset().left);

    // Get the percentage of the handle.
    var scroll_maximum = scroll_content.width() - scroll_frame.width();
    var percentage = Math.round((position_request.left/scroll_maximum) * 100);

    // Send the percentage to scrollbar.
    scrollbar.slider("value",percentage);

    // Attach other functions.
    exit_article (container_article);

});
```

results,

```
// 311 (block 1)
// 915 (block 2)
// 1120 (block 3)
// 1420 (block 4)
// 1375 (block 5)
```

but they should be,

```
// 307.44 (block 1)
// 922.32 (block 2)
// 1511.58 (block 3)
// 2126.46 (block 4)
// 2562 (block 5)
```

Here is the entire code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vtumh/1/).

Here is the test [site](http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/slider/).

Any idea how I can get the numbers right?

Comment: Your Fiddle is not functional, and your example site does not show the alerts.. can you possible log some of the values so we can see what is happening rather than reading your commenting only.

Comment: I have fixed the fiddle. See http://jsfiddle.net/Vtumh/1/

Comment: rlemon, you can go to my test site to see the value it returns http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/slider/  jsfiddle does not let me to load an ajax content. thanks.